# Execute servlet filters before the Spring Security filter chain

Tags: spring-security, servlet-filters

I'm introducing Spring Web Security in an already existing website. Now there has occured a problem:

I want my custom filters to be executed in the Tomcat filter chain **before** the Spring Security filter chain. I don't want them to be a part of this Spring Security filter chain.

All I have found is a solution in Spring Boot (see ["Spring - How to insert a filter before SpringSecurityFilterChain"](http://mtyurt.net/2015/07/15/spring-how-to-insert-a-filter-before-springsecurityfilterchain/)) - but I'm not using Spring Boot.

**Update 22.11.2016:**
Here is a part of my `web.xml` - only the custom filter is added here:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

The Spring Security filter chain is added by defining an AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class MySecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    ...
}
```

The outcome: The Spring security filters go first and only after this my custom filter.
How to swap this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define Web Security filter in your web.xml before springSecurity Filter declaraion,then this filter will not be part of spring security filter chain and your filter will execute before spring security filter chain.

Or if you want filter to exeute at web server level,You can define filter in  tomcat web.xml which is avaiable in conf/ directory.This filter will execute before your application filter chain.
But this filter will execute for all web applications runtime under your tomcat.

note that you'd also need to make the filter class available to all web applications, probably by putting it in the lib/ directory of Tomcat).

Comment: Yes, but my Spring Security filter chain is not added in 'web.xml' - I use 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' with '@EnableWebSecurity' annotation. Only the custom filter is declared in 'web.xml'. (see updated question). How to make my custom filter in this scenario the first of all filters?

Comment: It works like you describe it! I've now defined and mapped the springSecurityFilterChain via `web.xml` (and not like before via the `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`) and put my custom filter before this `filter-mapping`. After this I have put a breakpoint in one of the Spring Security chain filters and can see then in the debugger, that my custom filter executes before Spring Security. Thank you.